# Which GPU Should I buy for Deep Learning Project

Tags: graphics-cards, motherboard, memory

I have less than $1K as budget for my project.My project is predicting drug target interaction. I am going to use GPU on vector multiplication of visible layer and   neurons of hidden layer. I have 1007 drugs and 881 substructure of that drug  and 2000 neuons on no. of hidden layer. What I have to do is take one drug and provide its 881 substructures as input and multiply each values to 2000 neorons of one hidden layer again and again. When I did this from normal laptop just by using 200 drugs It took me 7 days. So I am thinking of using GPU and reducing time. 
SO please suggest what type of GPU do I need. Thank You.

Comment: What are the specs of the PC you want to put the GPU in?

Comment: IDK which gpu to select 
accroding to the need of GPU specs will be installed

Comment: Well, you're not going to get a Telsa (or whatever the AMD equivalent is) for that price, so I guess you'd want a GeForce or Radeon. Nvidia typically  has wider support. It also depends if you do double precision work or single precision (what software?). Also, is the 1k (USD?) budget for the GPU or the whole computer? And do you already have parts you can use?

Comment: thats whole computer budget. if possible